# How to run portworx backup to minio server

Tags: minio

Trying to configure portworx volume backups (`ptxctl cloudsnap`) to localhost minio server (emulating S3).
First step is to create cloud credentials using `ptxctl cred c`

e.g.

```
./pxctl credentials create --provider s3 --s3-access-key mybadaccesskey --s3-secret-key mybadsecretkey --s3-region local --s3-endpoint 10.0.0.1:9000
```

This results in:

> Error configuring cloud provider.Make sure the credentials are correct: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Get https://10.0.0.1:9000/: EOF

disabling SSL (which is not configured as this is just a localhost test) gives me:

```
./pxctl credentials create --provider s3 --s3-access-key mybadaccesskey --s3-secret-key mybadsecretkey --s3-region local --s3-endpoint 10.0.0.1:9000 --s3-disable-ssl
```

Which returns:

> Not authenticated with the secrets endpoint

I've tried this with both minio gateway (nas) and minio server - same result.
Portworx container is running within Rancher

Any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Resolved via instructions at https://docs.portworx.com/secrets/portworx-with-kvdb.html

i.e. set secret type to kvdb in /etc/pwx/config.json

`"secret": {
        "cluster_secret_key": "",
        "secret_type": "kvdb"
    },`

Then login using `./pxctl secrets kvdb login`

After this, credentials create was successful and subsequent cloudsnap backup.  Test was using --s3-disable-ssl switch

**Note** - kvdb is plain text so not suitable for production obvs.